# How can I view the reference image behind a cube?

Tags: image

I want to model an oven.
I want to use an image as a reference.

To do that, I use Image on a Plane:
[image]

The first thing I do is to add a cube to model this oven from it.

However, the geometry covers the reference image:

[image]

How do I make the cube transparent so that I can see the reference image again?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like your oven image is a mesh with texture not a reference image object. Press shift a then add a reference image. Then after selecting it in its image settings turn down the transparency.

Comment: @NascentSpace Making the image more transparent doesn't make the cube more transparent.

Comment: Alt Z to switch to transparency?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/205790/86891 for an alternative with alpha transparency

Answer (score 2):

Got it:

Go to Edit Mode, turn X-Ray on:

[image]